# Assign hours to User in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, datetime, methods, admin

I currently have an app where admin users can create, edit, show users and shifts and I need a little help here assigning hours to users. Firstly:

```
User has_many :shifts
  name:string
  email:string
  admin:boolean
```

I have user resources and in the users/index I manage my users with an admin for example: user/1/edit

I also have a shift model which belongs to a user which only the admin can create.

```
Shifts belongs_to :user
  start_time:datetime
  end_time:datetime
```

I now want to assign hours to a user (which can be set by the admin) where every time an admin creates a shift, the hours are reduced depending on how many hours are allocated to the user by the admin and eventually the user will not have any hours left. (unless the admin changes the hours)

So for example:

- admin creates a user as usual
- admin sets 20 hours for that user using a dropdown and updates the user on user/1/edit
- admin goes onto shifts and creates a 4 hour shift for that user
- admin checks back on the users/index page and sees that there are 14 hours remaining for that user

Answer (score 0):

You can make an after_create method in your Shift model... and have it do any logic you need.

What you described seems like it has a missing element to cover future weeks...